# Angular : converting blob into pdf

Tags: angular, spring-boot, pdf, blob

i created a SPRING BOOT service which can store different type of files. when i tried to consume this service into ANGULAR , the images works as well but when i try to display the pdf files with ng-pdf-viewer it doesn't work for me.

> my component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  tag: string;
  selectedFile: File;
  retrievedFile: any;
  base64Data: any;
  retrieveResonse: any;
  message: string;
  UserTag: any;
```

> ```
>   //Gets called when the user selects a file
> ```

```
  public onFileChanged(event) {
    //Select File
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }
```

> //Gets called when the user clicks on submit to upload the file

```
  onUpload() {
    console.log(this.selectedFile);
```

> //FormData API provides methods and properties to allow us easily prepare form data to be sent with POST HTTP requests.

```
    const uploadImageData = new FormData();
    uploadImageData.append("file", this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    uploadImageData.append("tag", this.tag);

    //Make a call to the Spring Boot Application to save the file
    this.httpClient
      .post("http://localhost:8080/do", uploadImageData, {
        observe: "response"
      })
      .subscribe(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          this.message = "Image uploaded successfully";
        } else {
          this.message = "Image not uploaded successfully";
        }
      });
  }
```

> //Gets called when the user clicks on retrieve filebutton to get the image from back end

```
  getFile() {
    //Make a call to Spring Boot to get the file Bytes.
    this.httpClient
      .get("http://localhost:8080/get/" + this.UserTag)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.retrieveResonse = res;
        this.base64Data = this.retrieveResonse.fileContent;
        if (
          this.retrieveResonse.fileType == "jpg" ||
          this.retrieveResonse.fileType == "png" ||
          this.retrieveResonse.fileType == "jpeg"
        ) {
          this.retrievedFile = "data:image/jpg;base64," + this.base64Data;
        }

        if (this.retrieveResonse.fileType == "pdf") {
          var blob = new Blob([this.base64Data], { type: "application/pdf" });
          this.retrievedFile = blob;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

> the get method:

```
public DBFile getFile( String fileTag) throws IOException {

        final Optional<DBFile> retrievedFile = fileRepo.findByFileTag(fileTag);
        DBFile img = new DBFile(retrievedFile.get().getName(), retrievedFile.get().getFileType(),
                decompressBytes(retrievedFile.get().getFileContent()),retrievedFile.get().getAddedAt(),retrievedFile.get().getFileTag());
```

> the decompress method:
>   // uncompress the file bytes before returning it to the angular
>   application

```
    public static byte[] decompressBytes(byte[] data) {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while (!inflater.finished()) {
                int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (DataFormatException e) {
        }
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    return img;
}
```

> my component.HTML

```html
<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>Upload Image</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="form">tag</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="tag"
        [(ngModel)]="tag"
        required
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="button" (click)="onUpload()" value="upload" />
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div *ngIf="message">{{ message }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
{{ this.retrieveResonse | json }}

<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      id="name"
      placeholder="File Tag"
      [(ngModel)]="UserTag"
      name="name"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="button" (click)="getFile()" value="Get File" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div>
      <pdf-viewer
        [src]="retrievedFile"
        [render-text]="true"
        style="display: block;"
      ></pdf-viewer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> console error:
>   [photo of the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AorT.png)

any help guys please?..

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: is your api return response in base64  format?

Comment: @SayoojVR yes , " Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url" i already added a photo shows the complete error.

Comment: @SayoojVR and i added the get method and uncompress method to make things more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant pass the blob file as src in pdf viewer, you have to convert it to safeUrl to preview. Hope this will help.

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser'; // import
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) // include in constructor

 if (this.retrieveResonse.fileType == "pdf") {
          var blob = new Blob([this._base64ToArrayBuffer(this.base64Data)], {
        type: "application/doc"
      });


      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      this.retrievedFile = window.open(url);
```

> the base64ToArrayBuffer methods:

```
_base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    const binary_string = window.atob(this.base64Data);
    const len = binary_string.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
  }
```

Comment: hello , thank you for your help but when i tried with ng2-pdf-viewer the same console error appears, and when i replaced it with <iframe> a error appears "UNSAFE VALUE USED IN A RESOURCE URL CONTEXT" so i create a pipe called "safe" and it resolves the problem but the iframe did not display the pdf..

Comment: and some warnings appears : "AngularCompilerPlugin: Forked Type Checker exited unexpectedly. Falling back to type checking on main thread."

Comment: if (this.retrieveResonse.fileType == "pdf") {
          var blob = new Blob([this.base64Data], { type: "application/pdf" });
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          window.open(url);
}

Comment: chk this is previewing

Comment: a pdf window opens and this error occurs "Failed to load PDF document"

Comment: ok i got it thank you,,, i added a method calls "_base64ToArrayBuffer" and i applied it to my base64 string and it works thank you you inspired me.

Comment: thank you for your effort with me, one last question do you think this  method will work for the docx files?